# How to add days to a defined Date

Tags: javascript, date

I'm trying to set a date like if it was 10 days ago and then I want to create a new date that simply adds 4 days to the first date.

```
    var date_1 = new Date();
    date_1.setDate(date_1.getDate() - 10);

    var date_2 = date_1;
    date_2.setDate(date_2.getDate() + 4);
```

The problem is that when I print the variables' dates, they have same value. It seems that date_2 modifies also the date_1.

The output are both: Date 2018-05-28 and I want

date_1 = Date 2018-05-24

date_2 = Date 2018-05-28

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply create a new Date object using date_1's time. Otherwise you're creating a reference only, that will mutate the original object too

```js
const date_1 = new Date();
date_1.setDate(date_1.getDate() - 10);

const date_2 = new Date(date_1);
date_2.setDate(date_2.getDate() + 4);

console.log(date_1, date_2)
```

Comment: You can simplify it a bit with `date_2 = new Date(date_1)` or even `date_2 = new date(date_1.setDate(date_1.getDate() - 10))`. ;-)

Comment: The second one doesn't seem to work @RobG . Changed it to omit getTime() though. Thanks